# Assigning textures to a certain area of the model?

Tags: modeling, texturing, 3d-view, edit-mode, sculpting

How can I apply textures from the **selected areas** to the model **?**

[image]

Comment: the simplest way would be to assign it a new material

Comment: Could you give me a step by step guide by sending me a reply?

Comment: what kind of texture are you talking about? are you using an image texture?

Comment: Yes, I want to apply an image texture to that certain area.

Comment: please read this and tell if it answers: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: Yes, that answers the question. Thanks.